# SendKeys ctrl + s not saving file

Tags: excel, vba, sendkeys

I have a problem with SendKeys "^s".
If I save my csv file with ActiveWorkbook.Save I'm getting an error with another software that uses this csv file to input data to system. Could someone help me with that?

```
Sub Copy_selected_to_CIM_Item()
    Workbooks("ITEM.csv").Activate
    Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    SendKeys "^s"
End Sub
```

I was using SendKeys "^s" yesterday and it seemed to work fine but today I'm back on the code and SendKeys "^s" is not doing anything.

Comment: Why don't you use `Workbooks("ITEM.csv").Save`? Using Sendkeys seems like a horrible idea to me.

Comment: I was using `Workbooks("ITEM.csv").Save` but with that I'm getting and error in another software. It seems it is not same as ctrl+c.
If I use ctrl + c in the csv file, it is working.